# Object instantiation and assignment in a class

Tags: java, class, instantiation

Where can an object be instantiated and assigned inside a class? i.e does the assignment have to take place inside one of the class methods?

```
public class Foo{

   Bar b1 = new Bar();
   Bar b2;

   void Foo(){
      b2 = new Bar();
   }
}
```

Is `b1` a valid instantiation?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid instantiation

Comment: Did you try the code you've presented before asking?

Comment: Why don'y you try it yourself? the compiler will tell you if it's a valid instantiation or not. And BTW, `Foo()` is not a constructor for the class, is a method. A constructor must not declare a return type.

Comment: but that constructor isn't valid.

Comment: Ideally it should be initiated inside the constructor.

Comment: try this himself will not work because of the syntax of the constructor

Comment: @11684 An IDE can tell him if it's valid, even if some other part isn't.

Comment: Haha, bit harsh with the down-votes. A simplistic question for some maybe, but not everyone is an experienced programmer.

Comment: @11684 that _is_ valid Java code. `Foo()` is not a constructor, but a method, and it will compile just fine.

Comment: @Nate I think people don't downvote, because the question is too "easy", but because you don't seem to have tested it yourself.

Comment: @Baz that is most likely true but I thought presenting it to experienced developers might be a better idea. It maybe a valid operation but it might not be the best practice due to information I am unaware of that some people might be happy to shed some light upon.

Comment: @Nate Fair enough. Then maybe you should specifically ask if this is "good practice" or not, rather than asking if it's valid. Just a tip for future questions :)

Comment: @Nate - But ... that's not what you asked ;) As for the practice ... it depends on what you're doing. You might look into dependency injection and why that's a good practice, it ties directly to your question.

Comment: @Baz True, this is not what I asked and I will strive to be more specific next time.

Comment: @11684 Because whenever you declare a variable in class, its the property of that class, and whenever object of this class is created that property should have some default value. Logically it is not necessary but conceptually it makes sense.

Comment: @Óscar López Don't all classes need to declare a valid constructor?

Comment: @Nate A default no-args constructor is implicitly declared for all classes if none is provided explicitly

Comment: @Óscar López -6 votes later and I've learned so many new things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Yes it is valid. Every instance of the Foo class will have a field called b1 which has a new Bar instance.

Comment: @Nate If you want to learn more about the tricks and traps in the way Java works, get yourself a copy of Joshua Bloch's book **Effective Java (Second Edition)**. I gained more wisdom in Java programming from reading his book than I did from an entire University degree course.